# Escaping command in CMD Dockerfile

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

To execute sbt to execute a specific Main method I use:

```
 sbt "run-main tickdata.Main"
```

How should the command `sbt "run-main tickdata.Main"` be used within docker.

I've tried adding to `Dockerfile` :

```
CMD ["sbt" , "\"run-main tickdata.Main\""]
```

But receive error :

```
[error] Expected letter
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Expected '!'
[error] Expected '+'
[error] Expected '++'
[error] Expected '^'
[error] Expected '^^'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected 'early('
[error] Expected '-'
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected 'all'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected key
[error] "run-main tickdata.Main"
[error] ^
```

Comment: What happens if you try just with `CMD ["sbt" , "run-main tickdata.Main"]`? - Also, note that is not common to have a **docker** image with a whole **sbt** project inside it. You usually create a **docker** image with a normal **java** app _(just the JRE)_ which would be smaller. faster & simpler. If the project is not too complñex you can just use **sbt-assembly** to generate a single jar and just do a `java -jar jar` on the CMD, or you can look to **sbt-native-packager** to create a more robust docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add `"` and escape them.

Wrapping text in `"` is used to make sure that it will be passed on as one argument instead of several when spaces are used to separate them, but if you pass arguments (and program) as `String`s separated by commas you don't have to escape them.

sbt is expecting `run-main tickdata.Main` as one parameter - in shell it has to be done via `"run-main tickdata.Main"` to make sure that shell will pass `run-main tickdata.Main` as single argument (without quotations!). Docker also removes these quotation marks, so if you add you own and escape them then sbt receives command `"run-main tickdata.Main"` instead of `run-main tickdata.Main` and it doesn't know how to parse it.

So just

```
CMD ["sbt" , "run-main tickdata.Main"]
```

About whether it makes sense, see @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez comment.